# Some of the campaigns of account not showing to the user

Tags: administration

I am facing an issue that, some of the campaigns in an account is not visible to the user. User is able to see few campaigns of the same account.

Not sure how to proceed in this issue. Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to the fact that the user has a restricted view. Go to the user's profile and check if the view all data is enabled for Account/Campaign objects

Comment: Hi Marc, i notice the profile, it does not have view all data. Account owned by the user, so he should have visibility to the campaigns related to that account right?  few campaigns are visible for and others are not.

Answer (score 0):

Campaigns will only be visible if the sharing permissions are applicable to that user. If you OWD sharing for Campaigns is Public they will need Read access to the Campaign object. If your sharing setting is Private then the campaign will need to be shared to that user either directly or via a role/group they inhabit.